# Close Blackberry Map after use of custom menu item

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-maps

I created for BlackberryMaps a own menu item with help of "MenuItem" and invoke Blackberry Maps. After using this Item the current location (MapView) should be send back to my Application. This works fine.

The problem is I found no solution for closing the app after using the menu Item. Is there a possibility to close Blackberry Maps? Or set my own App to foreground?

```
private static class MapMenuItem  extends ApplicationMenuItem {
//creates a new MenuItem for Blackberry Maps and defines the action which should //happen after a click on the MenuItem
            CustomDialog_GPS customDialogGps;
            StartScreen startScreen;

            MapMenuItem(StartScreen startScreen, CustomDialog_GPS customDialogGps) {
               super(20);
               this.startScreen = startScreen;  
               this.customDialogGps = customDialogGps;
            }
            public String toString() {
            //creates the name for the navigation Menu  
               String itemName = ""+_res.getString(CUSTOMDIALOG_GPS_USE_AS_NEW_LOCATION);
               return itemName;
            }
            public Object run(Object context) {
            //defines what should happen after a click on the menu

            //get the location at which the cursor is pointing at.  
               MapView mv = (MapView)context;

               if (mv != null) {                
                  //opens a method inside of CustomDialogGPS which handles the latitude and longitude                     
                   customDialogGps.saveAdjustedPosition(mv);

                  //TODO pop Screen
                  //Screen screen = (Screen)UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen();           
               }
               else {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Context is null, expected a MapView instance");
               }
               return null;
            }

       }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... Shouldn't the user be closing the maps to return to your application? Why should your application close the map?

Comment: I open Blackberry Maps to define a location and get the gps coordinates. If the user has choosen the location in blackberry maps he should use the menue Item which says "use this as location". The current Map View is send to the app and the app handles the coordinates of the map view. But the problem is the blackberry map is still open :/ and the user has to close blackberry maps to get back to the application...

Comment: why do you need to get a location from the map? why not get the current location using the LocationProvider?

Comment: in this application I need a user defined location which should be choosable on a blackberry map.

Comment: I see, I've added an answer below on how you can achieve this effect. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't close another app programmatically (Actually you can if you know where is menu item to close for example) but you can foreground your app `UiApplication.getApplication().requestForeground()`. What is probably appropriate solution for you.

Comment: Thx Eugen. This solution works. Now I've got the described open BB Maps after closing the App but the normal closing of the BB Maps during the runtime "works".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the user to the Maps application, which is outside your app and you have no control over it, create your own screen with a [MapField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/lbs/MapField.html) in it. Using your own screen and perhaps extending the MapField class to override functions if needed, allows you to go back to the previous screen once the user selects a location.

Comment: Thx tamar. I tried this. If Iam right The MapField only provides a "Field" which shows a fix section of the map. Next thing would be to implement the zoom and "move" functionality and then there are no functions like "search location"(by name/street). This seems to me too much effort and I will try requestForeground() first.